# Nashorn throwing java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.getContext

Tags: java, nashorn

I am trying to use Nashorn in openjdk version "1.8.0_91". My code is like below.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager(null);
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(getJSReaderFromResorces("env.nashorn.1.2.js"));
```

Its throwing an exception on the last line like below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.getContext
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.NativeJavaPackage.classNotFound(NativeJavaPackage.java:162)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1249)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:623)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
engine.eval(getJSReaderFromResorces("env.nashorn.1.2.js"));
```

It appears that this script uses Nashorn internal class called "jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context". This is from a package called "jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime". When you run with security manager set on, this package is access protected and so not visible to scripts.

In any case, accessing nashorn internal /implementation classes is a good idea - as there are no compatibility guarantees on those.

With java 9, these packages are not exported from nashorn module and so won't be accessible regardless of security manager turned on/off.